# Why is my Google Maps overflowing my CSS grid container?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Part of my Google Maps is cut off at the bottom. I have the Google Maps in a CSS grid container, but it seems to overflow (?) the grid. I currently have the height of the grid-area (google-map) that the Google Maps occupy set to "100vh". I previously had the height set to "100%", but it only occupied half of the browser viewport. The longer the viewport is, the more cut off the Google Maps is at the bottom.

This is a very minor issue that doesn't affect the application itself, but It just bugs me that the entire Google Map isn't shown.

Here are some screenshots; the first screenshot is a maximized (Google Chrome) browser and the second is a minimized browser. I circled the difference between the two screenshots in red.

[image]
[image]

Here is the code within App.vue:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <Search id="search-bar" @location="getEvents"/>
        <div id="content">
            <EventList id="event-list" @markerIndex="getMarkerIndex" :events="events"/>
            <GoogleMaps id="google-map" :events="events" :markerIndex="markerIndex"/>
        </div>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
    //
</script>

<style lang="scss">

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#app {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "search"
    "content";
}

#content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-area: 'content';
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% auto;
  grid-template-areas: "list" "map";
}

#search-bar {
  grid-area: "search";
  width: 100vw;
  height: 5vh;
}

#event-list {
  grid-area: "list";
}

#google-map {
  grid-area: "map";
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
</style>
```

Comment: can you reproduce this in any other browser?

Comment: @ATomCalledStu Yeah, it's the same in Firefox and Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a search bar element above your google map element. How is the map supposed to take up `100vh` if there is another element taking up `5vh`? Change your map container height to `95vh`.

Here is a very simple fiddle which illustrates what's happening. In this example, both the `google-map` and `content` elements are defined as `height=95vh`. Note that this is redundant, and you could just list your map as `height=100%`.

https://jsfiddle.net/9ks2my0a/

Comment: That....that makes a whole lot of sense. Such an oversight on my part. Thank you very much!

Comment: @chataolauj oversight is the name of the game when you're staring at numbers and letters all day :)